# How to Programmatically Trigger the "Capture" Button for SDI Video Output to a Blackmagic Card in Unreal Engine 5 Packaged Project

Tags: visual-c++, unreal-engine5, unreal-blueprint, unreal

I'm working on a project in Unreal Engine 5 where I'm using the "Capture Media" window under the Virtual Production menu to output SDI video to a Blackmagic card. In the Unreal Engine IDE, I can manually press the "Capture" button to start sending the output to the Blackmagic card.

However, when I package the project and run the application, this button is unavailable in the packaged project. I need a way to programmatically trigger the "Capture" button at the startup of the packaged application.

Here are some specifics about my setup:

Unreal Engine 5
Blackmagic capture card
"Capture Media" functionality used for SDI video output
I'm looking for guidance on how to automate this process using Blueprints or C++ in my Unreal Engine project. I've checked the Virtual Production API, but I'm not sure how to replicate the button press action in code.